# Do we need Unity questions?

Tags: discussion

Don't get me wrong, I love Unity. I think it's a great engine. But surely we should refer people along to [Unity's official QA website?](http://answers.unity3d.com/) That's a better place for their questions (even if it is terribly built compared to SE).

Answer (score 16):

I think Unity questions are fine.

Unity Answers isn't part of the StackExchange network. We don't close questions on UDK, Ogre, or OpenGL, or Direct3D (et cetera) with a link to the appropriate support site or forums for the technology -- there's no reason to do to so unilaterally for Unity questions just because Unity's official support site is a StackExchange look-alike.

Comment: I agree with this, though there might be certain questions where directing the asker to the Unity Q&A site is a good idea (or at least mention the fact that there is a Unity Q&A site)

Comment: yeah I agree with this as well. Every engine/technology has it's own forum/QA site related to it, but if it's not part of SE it should be perfectly fine to use. Otherwise like Josh stated we would have to close OpenGL, Direct3D, C++ to other appropriate links

Answer (score 10):

Maybe I'm biased (I am), but the moderation here is a lot better than the moderation over there.

I, for one, welcome good Unity questions.  If the questions help drive traffic to our site, they're on topic, and they "help make the internet a better place", all the better.

Comment: +1 for the moderators here :) - Unity's site was a *lot* worse in terms of bad questions, duplicate questions (and I mean the same person posting the same question three times in a row...), etc. Plus, they moved from using the SE 1.0 codebase to QATO, which isn't nearly as usable as the new SE 2.0 that all the SE sites now run on.

Answer (score 4):

On Unity Answers you often have people that don't know how to handle the QA-system correctly.

Often people ask only one question and then disappear.

You get a lof of questions there, that could be answered with a look at the manual/reference.

For my part I'ts nice to know I could post a question here and might get an answer from someone that has a broader horizon (a not ONLY Unity user).

Answer (score 3):

I was a unity answers member before I joined this site, but I always get higher quality answers here. Most of my questions have deeper CS requirements even if it's a Unity question, so that may account for my experience.

Answer (score -3):

Unity questions belong on UnityAnswers or the Unity Forums. I think wherever possible, technology-specific questions should be asked on fora dedicated to that technology, so as to contribute to those individual resources. XNA to its own, Unity to its own, iPhone dev to its own, etc. etc.

The only time users should really opt for this site over those sites is when the question tends more toward technology-agnostic games or simulation-related problem-solving. The best questions on this site, and the best answers, rarely have to do with individual technologies, IMO.

Wouldn't you rather have one single go-to point for a technology you are learning about, than to have to hunt high and low on the web (much fun as that might seem)?

Comment: The way I see it, if somebody has a specific problem that isn't easily googleable, then a SE site that covers the topic should either 1) have a question on it or 2) be the place where somebody can ask it.